# Dynamo DB filter expression using IN operator with numeric array variable

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to execute a query with the following payload

```
payload = {
        TableName : "fleet_list",
        IndexName : "vehicle_type-department-index",
        KeyConditionExpression : "vehicle_type = :v",
        FilterExpression : "(id IN (:list))",
        ExpressionAttributeValues : {
            ":v" : "Car",
            ":list" : [1947, 4397].join()
        }
    }
```

However the query does not work. it does work however if :list : 1947 . Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

- Change `FilterExpression : "(id IN (:list))",` to `FilterExpression : "(id IN (:id1, :id2))",`.
- Change `":list" : [1947, 4397].join()` to `":id1": 1947, ":id2": 4397`.