# DynamoDB: ComparisonOperator "IN" doesn't work

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js

[JavaScript SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#query-property)

I am trying to use ComparisonOperator "IN" in KeyConditions of my query

```
var params = {
            TableName: 'xxxxx',
            KeyConditions: {
                'uuid': {
                  ComparisonOperator: 'IN',  /* required */
                  AttributeValueList: [
                    "abc", "def", "ghi" 
                  ]
                }              }

        };
var dynamoQueryPromise = dynamoClient.query(params).promise();
...
```

But I received error:

> ValidationException: Attempted conditional constraint is not an
>   indexable operation

does operation "IN" not available?

Any advice is appreciated.

****UPDATE*****

I followed a potential suggestion from duplicated question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32671509/in-statement-in-dynamodb)

It suggested to use the "IN" operation in FilterExpression not KeyConditionExpression

I updated my code:

create index 'my-index' with PK = 'staff'

```
var keyExpr = "#staff = :staff";
var filterExpr = " #phone IN :phone"

var attributeNames = new Object();
attributeNames["#staff"] = 'staff';
attributeNames["#phone"] = 'phone';

var attributeValues = new Object();
attributeValues[":staff"] = 'A1';
attributeValues[":phone"] = ['0012341', '12342134', '214234124'];
var params = {
      TableName: 'xxxxxx',
      IndexName: 'my-index',
      KeyConditionExpression: keyExpr,
      FilterExpression: filterExpr,
      ExpressionAttributeNames: attributeNames,
      ExpressionAttributeValues: attributeValues
}
...
```

Results: error

> ValidationException: Invalid FilterExpression: Syntax error; token:
>   ":phone", near: "IN:phone"

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["IN" statement in dynamodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32671509/in-statement-in-dynamodb)

Comment: I read the post, it suggested to use the "IN" in FilterExpression, I tried and "IN" still doesn't work. The AWS SDK documents is not updated and incorrect info, so frustrated ...

Comment: No, it says [IN isn't supported.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32751240/542251)

Comment: Hi Liam, thanks for figuring it out, so is there any way to use "IN" for filter DynamoDB query ? or Amazon removed this operation from its SDK

Comment: Not sure, not my area I'm afraid I just saw the duplicate. If you want to ask that question I'd suggest you edit your question and include a link to the potential duplicate

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information posted, couldn't figure out whether "phone" is your sort key. However DynamoDB query operator IN is not supported for indexed keys.

For non-indexed keys make sure your AttributeNames list & AttributeValues are declared properly.

Adding a link here for your reference: [Dynamo DB filter expression using IN operator with numeric array variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42120562/dynamo-db-filter-expression-using-in-operator-with-numeric-array-variable)